# how to get the total count based from a json object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to get the count of particular value from a json object

From the below data I want to get the count of people in ny city. The expectation would be from the below data is `2`

```
mockdata: {
  "sampleData": [{
      "name": "jane",
      "city": "ny"
    },
    {
      "name": "jack",
      "city": "ny"
    },
    {
      "name": "brandon",
      "city": "ca"
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried:

```
mockdata.filter(item => item.value == "ny").length;
```

But I am not able to get the exact count.

Comment: `mockdata.sampleData.filter(item => item.city == 'ny').length`

Comment: @MohammadUsman is on to something. mockdata is an object with one property - sampleData. It's sampleData that has the array of objects you want to filter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below :

```
let mockdata = {
                    "sampleData" : [{
                        "name": "jane",
                        "city": "ny"
                    },
                        {
                            "name": "jack",
                            "city": "ny"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "brandon",
                            "city": "ca"
                        }]
                }
console.log(mockdata.sampleData.filter(item => item.city == 'ca').length)
```

OR

```
console.log(mockdata.sampleData.filter(item => item.city == 'ny').length)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data was as follows:

```
const mockdata = {
  "sampleData": [
    {"name": "jane", "city": "ny"},
    {"name": "jack", "city": "ny"},
    {"name": "brandon", "city": "ca"}
  ]
}
```

You can do the following:

```
mockdata.sampleData.filter(item => item.city === 'ny').length
```

Answer (score 0):

`filter` works on array and `mockdata` is an object. So, `mockdata.filter` should be `mockdata.sampleData.filter`.

```
mockData.sampleData.filter(item => item.city == "ny").length
```

You can also use reduce, to create object grouped by cities, and then just pass the city name to get the `count`.

```js
const mockData = {
  "sampleData": [{
      "name": "jane",
      "city": "ny"
    },
    {
      "name": "jack",
      "city": "ny"
    },
    {
      "name": "brandon",
      "city": "ca"
    }
  ]
};

const groupByCity = mockData.sampleData.reduce((a, {city}) => {
  a[city] = (a[city] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(groupByCity["ny"]);
console.log(groupByCity["ca"]);
```